# Error in internet explorer onchange

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have an input text that call a javascript function through onchange method.

```
var desc= document.getElementById('descricao').value;
var quantia_anterior= document.getElementById('quantia_hidden').value.trim();
var quantia=document.getElementById('quantia2').value.trim();
var n=desc.replace(quantia_anterior+" €",quantia);
document.getElementById('descricao').value = n;
```

So, it runs correctly in the google chrome, but in internet explorer don't works.

Comment: is the `.trim()` method defined on the String returned in IE (e.g. have you prototyped this?

Comment: @Adriano its different because the onchange is trigger in ie, but method replace dont work